# When hovering over child element, parent element thinks I'm doing mouseleave()

Tags: jquery

This is clearly not the case though.

My JS :

```
$(".job_charge.item-block").live({
  mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).find('.edit-and-delete').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).find('.edit-and-delete').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

my HTML :

```
<div id="job_charge_2244" class="item-block job_charge">
          <div class="edit-and-delete right">
          </div>
</div>
```

The CSS :

```
.item-block.job_charge
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc
  display: inline-block
  padding-bottom: 15px
  width: 650px

  .edit-and-delete
    position: relative
    display: none
    top: 25px
    right: 5px
    float: right
    a
      margin-right: 8px
```

I've gone bananas. When I mouse over the links in my inner div, then immediately, it triggers a mouse-leave function and they hide. This div is naturally in `position: relative`, but I have also placed it in `block` and it still has the same issue.

The parent div is in `inline-block`.

Comment: Show us you `CSS` for both parent and child elements. Is it possible that child element is set to `float` and you parent is actually smaller than you would expect?

Comment: This is because as far as the DOM is concerned, you ARE leaving the parent element, then re-entering it again as you move the mouse over a child element. Look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseover) for some ideas about this.

Comment: The child element is `float: right` right now..

Comment: Whoa.. I didn't know float killed the radio star. @jperovic you were absolutely correct. Floating ruined it. Thanks so much for that !!

Comment: Actually, according to the documentation, mouseenter and mouseleave are the components of hover(), so mouseleave should NOT be triggered by moving over a child element.  I didn't know float killed this either.

Comment: @jperovic, Would you mind providing that as an answer so I can mark it complete? I think this is noteworthy for the community to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that child element is set to `float` and you parent is actually smaller than you would expect. Try either removing `float` or putting `overflow: auto` on parent...

Comment: In my case I had to set the z-index of the child element to 1, because it was absolutely positioned.  Don't know why, 'cause this aways holds true.

Comment: Thanks for the overflow:auto on parent containing floated elements, I was not-so-blissfully unaware of this.

Comment: for me it was `overflow: hidden`

Comment: How would `overflow: hidden` help with floating child elements?

Comment: overflow: auto fixed this annoying issue for me with display: flex on the parent. The parent div seemed to cover everything in devtools, so I was completely in the wild.

Answer (score 15):

The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are specifically designed to handle this situation correctly. When you enter a child element, there is no `mouseleave` event triggered for the parent, provided that the child element actually is inside the parent element.

When I try your code, it doesn't trigger the `mouseleave` event when I hover the child element:

http://jsfiddle.net/baCsd/

I think that you have something in your code that actually places the child element *outside* the parent element, and that's why the `mouseleave` event is triggered.

For example, if there is no content in the parent element it's only the padding that gives it height, so it's only `15px` high, and the `position: relative; top: 25px;` could place the child element below the bottom of the parent element.

Comment: He might be using mouseout.

Comment: when you say "inside", do you mean "visually" or "hierarchically"? For example, I'd like not to get a "mouseleave" on a DIV when hovering an absolutely positioned SPAN (not a descendant) that happens to be displayed on top of the DIV. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

try this instead.. it is basically the same but with use of .hover which is the combined function of mouseenter and mouseleave.. Also it does not have the bug with leaving the parent when entering the child.

```
$(".job_charge.item-block").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".edit-and-delete").fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).children(".edit-and-delete").fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YWRRZ/4/ <-- My fiddle link where you can test it

Comment: This code will just do the same as the code in the question. The documentation says that the `hover` method is shorthand for `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`.

Comment: Absolutely, but a force of habit compelled me to show the .hover way

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `mouseout` instead of the `mouseleave` event

Comment: onMouseOut is doing the opposite, it is triggered when mouse leaves any child component